# mutiple linear regression, omitted variable bias and causal effect

Tags: regression, linear-regression, causality

1. I am struggling with the meaning of MLR, from my original understanding, the MLR intended to include more independent variables to make better predictions(independent variables could be either factor or continuous variables). Whereas from the Econometrics textbook, they call solving omitted variable bias by grouping data, this is adding the factor to the model. **So isn't continuous independent variables resolve omitted variable bias?**
2. In detecting the causal effect model, how does it differ from **ACOVA**? Suppose we investigate the $Sex$(factor with 2 levels) affecting the $Earnings$, with proper randomisation assigned

$$
Earnings =\beta_0+\beta_1Sex+\beta_2Edu+\sum_{i=1}\beta_ivariables_i
$$

**Isn't the $\beta_1$ capture the causal effect of $Sex$?**

Comment: You can use factor variables or continuous variables, depending on which is more appropriate for the context. In MLR, $\beta_1$ doesn't capture the causal effect of $sex$, but the effect of $sex$ *holding all other variables in the regression constant*. And, this only applies if the [OLS assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Assumptions) are satisfied, otherwise you may still have omitted variable bias that is not resolved by the additional variables.

Comment: @AmaanM thank you for your reply. Why can't $beta_1$ be the causal effect as randomisation assigned? How to investigate the causal in this example?

Comment: First, how are you randomizing sex and education? Even if you could, that takes care of the exogeneity issue, but you have to be sure you have the correct specification. Even if that's true, the interpretation is still conditional on the other explanatory variables. Best case, $\beta_1$ is the causal effect of $sex$, but only within the context of holding the other explanatory variables constant. You can't interpret it as the overall effect, because there are other distributional differences in the sample (e.g., perhaps women are more educated than men).

Comment: Side comment: when you write *"more independent variables to make better predictions"*, it's not necessarily true. Adding variables makes a better fit ($R^2$ is larger, geometrically you project $y$ on a larger space, so $\hat y$ is closer to $y$). However, this may produce worse predictions in the case of [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting). It's tempting, but it's really a bad idea to just add regressors with the hope to have a better regression. If you want good predictions, the correct criterium is not the $R^2$, you better try cross validation.

Answer (score 2):

1. So isn't continuous independent variables resolve omitted variable bias?

Not necessary. If all the variables that you added, either continuous or categorical, are the all possible confounders - then yes, you "control" for all possible confounders and the OLS of $\beta_1$ is asymptotically unbiased. Otherwise - no. In practice, you can never know what are the all possible confounders.

2. Isn't the $β_1$ capture the causal effect of Sex?

As was mentioned in the comments - no. You cannot randomized sex as in RCTs. Even if we assume that the sex of the child is something random, the sex can still effect various other variables (including education), namely its effect maybe mediated through other variables. Therefore, $\beta_1$ is not the causal effect of sex on earnings. If there are no omitted confounders, then it maybe the direct effect of sex on earnings.  Otherwise (with omitted variables) it is just a measure of association in the estimated model.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What about grouping the sex, then two samples differences in sex and other variables (without exogenity problem) are the same on average between two groups. Under such a situation can we say $\beta_1$ is the causal?

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "grouping by sex"? The main problem is that sex cannot be assigned randomly (or treated like that) in the sense of randomized controlled trial. Therefore, even without omitted confounders, $\beta_1$ might be only a direct effect that, I would guess, comprise a small portion of the total causal effect that probably goes through bunch of other variables.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What if not randomised the sex, what is the problem of getting males and females separately into two groups and measuring their differences in obtaining the causal effect of $\beta_1$, under above no omitted cofounders and no exogenity assumption, other variables are equal on average between female and male groups.